# Creating class with vm.runInNewContext (forcing class expression instead of class declaration in ES6)

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6, atom-editor

I am debugging another person's package (currently unmaintained) that runs in the [Atom](https://atom.io) editor. At one point, this package uses `vm.runInContext` to define a class object, using code equivalent to the following:

```
const vm = require('vm')
myClass = vm.runInNewContext('class x {}', {}, 'file')
```

I think this code runs in `node.js`, but I don't really know all the details of Atom's javascript environment. At any rate, I'm pretty sure it's running in ES6 or later. I believe that when this package was last updated in April 2017, the call to `vm.runInNewContext` returned a valid class object. However, it currently returns `undefined`, probably due to some upgrade in Atom since then (maybe around June 1, 2018). Because of this, references to attributes of `myClass` now fail, which is the bug I am trying to fix.

I believe what is happening here is that javascript interprets the `class x {}` code as a class declaration, which has no value, so `vm.runInNewContext` returns `undefined`. So I'm looking for a graceful way to force this code to return a class, rather than `undefined`. I have found the following possibilities:

```
// add a reference to the class, which will be returned as the final value
vm.runInNewContext('class x {}; x', {}, 'file')

// use an assignment, which treats this as a class expression, 
// then the assignment is returned as the final value
vm.runInNewContext('var x; x = class x {}', {}, 'file')
// note: a simpler version ('var x = class x {}') returns undefined

// wrap the class statement in parentheses, so it is evaluated as
// a class expression instead of a class declaration
vm.runInNewContext('(class x {})', {}, 'file')
```

All of these work, but they all seem clunky. Is there some "standard" way to force javascript / ES6 to treat `class x {}` as a class expression rather than a class declaration?

Comment: You've already hit upon it - the standard way to convert things to an expression in JS-wordld is to use parens. `vm.runInNewContext('(class x {})', {}, 'file')` is the answer you're looking for, and honestly isn't really that clunky.

Comment: @AnilRedshift, thanks for the confirmation, I'll go with the parentheses. I'm not sure how the author got away without them in the first place, but they seem like a pretty minimal and clear change to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour isn't specific to Node.js `vm.runInNewContext`. The code should be forced to be evaulated as expression.

```
eval('function foo () {}') === undefined
```

because it's treated as function declaration instead of function expression. For the same reason this line will result in syntax error:

```
function () {};
```

It isn't valid function declaration and it's not used as expression.

So parentheses

```
vm.runInNewContext('(class x {})', {}, 'file')
```

or comma operator

```
vm.runInNewContext('0, class x {}', {}, 'file')
```

are conventional ways to make evaluated code an expression.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know these are the standard solutions. I didn't know about the comma operator, but I think I prefer the parentheses anyway.

Comment: Yes, parentheses are usual in a situation like this one.